# Python multiprocessing code runs fine, but does not terminate

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have this code (I apologize that it is almost an exact copy-paste from my working code. I don't know where the problem might be, hence I am putting the whole of it here):

```
def init(Q):
    """Serves to initialize the queue across all child processes"""
    global q
    q = Q

def queue_manager(q):
    """Listens on the queue, and writes pushed data to file"""
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        key, preds = data
        with pd.HDFStore(hdf_out, mode='a', complevel=5, complib='blosc') as out_store:
            out_store.append(key, preds)

def writer(message):
    """Pushes messages to queue"""
    q.put(message)

def reader(key):
    """Reads data from store, selects required days, processes it"""
    try:
        # Read the data
        with pd.HDFStore(hdf_in, mode='r') as in_store:
            df = in_store[key]
    except KeyError as ke:
        # Almost guaranteed to not happen
        return (key, pd.DataFrame())
    else:
        # Executes only if exception is not raised
        fit_df = df[(df.index >= '2016-09-11') & \
                    (df.index < '2016-09-25') & \
                    (df.index.dayofweek < 5)].copy()
        pre_df = df[(df.index >= '2016-09-18') & \
                    (df.index < '2016-10-2') & \
                    (df.index.dayofweek < 5)].copy()
        del df
        # model_wrapper below is a custom function in another module.
        # It works fine.
        models, preds = model_wrapper(fit_df=fit_df, pre_df=pre_df)
        if preds is not None:
            writer((key, preds))
            del preds
    return (key, models)

def main():
    sensors = pd.read_csv('sens_metadata.csv', index_col=[0])
    nprocs = int(cpu_count() - 0)
    maxproc = 10
    q = Queue()
    t = Thread(target=queue_manager, args=(q,))

    print("Starting process at\t{}".format(dt.now().time()))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    t.start()
    with Pool(processes=nprocs, maxtasksperchild=maxproc, initializer=init,
              initargs=(q,)) as p:
        models = p.map(reader, sensors.index.tolist(), 1)
    print("Processing done at\t{}".format(dt.now().time()))
    print("\nJoining Thread, and finishing writing predictions")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    q.put(None)
    t.join()
    print("Thread joined successfully at\t{}".format(dt.now().time()))
    print("\nConcatenating models and serializing to pickle")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    pd.concat(dict(models)).to_pickle(path + 'models.pickle')
    print("Pickled successfully at\t{}".format(dt.now().time()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code behaves like a badly biased coin toss. Most of the time it does not work, sometimes, it works. When it runs, I know it takes about 2.5 hours to finish running the whole data (all the `keys`). 9 out of 10 runs, it will process all the data, I see the data in the `hdf_out` file, but the multiprocessing pool does not join. All the child processes are active, but not doing any work. I just don't understand why the program might be hung like that.

When that happens, I don't see the `"Processing done at ..."` and the `"Joining Thread, ..."` messages I have. Also, if I give it smaller datasets, it finishes. If I exclude calculation of `preds` it finishes. I cannot exclude calculation of `models` without heavy modification which won't be conducive to the rest of the project.

I don't know why this might be happening. I am using Linux (Kubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently dropping the `maxtaskperchild` kwag solves the issue. Why is something I don't clearly understand. I suppose it has to do with the distinction between fork process (the default on Linux) and spawn process (the only option on Windows).

With fork process `maxtaskperchild` is apparently not required because performance is better without it. I noticed memory use improved by dropping `maxtaskperchild`. Memory is not hogged by the child processes but is shared from the parent process. However, the time I had to use Windows, the `maxtaskperchild` was a crucial way of preventing a child process from bloating up, especially when running memory intensive tasks with a long task list.

Someone who knows what's happening better, please feel free to edit this answer.